# Plot in subplot figure not showing

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, text

The plot in one of the figure boxes is not showing. Both plots are within one figure box, but not plotted within one each. Below is an image of what I mean:[image]

The plots should be divided between one figure box each. Here is the code for the plotting:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
cm = plt.get_cmap('gist_rainbow')
ax.set_color_cycle([cm(1.*i/NUM_COLORS_RIGHT) for i in range(NUM_COLORS_RIGHT)])
ax.grid(True)
plt.title('Right IRI data per mile for verification runs:')
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=8)
plt.hold(True)

ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
cm = plt.get_cmap('gist_rainbow')
ax.set_color_cycle([cm(1.*i/NUM_COLORS_LEFT) for i in range(NUM_COLORS_LEFT)])
ax.grid(True)
plt.title('Left IRI data per mile for verification runs:')
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=8)
plt.hold(True)

for i in range(NUM_COLORS_RIGHT):
    plt.subplot(2,1,1)
    ax.plot(dataR[i],linewidth=2)
    if dataR[i] != dataR[-1]:
        continue
    else: break

for d in range(NUM_COLORS_LEFT):
    plt.subplot(2,1,2)
    ax.plot(dataL[d],label = d,linewidth=2)
    ax.legend(loc='lower right',borderaxespad=-4,bbox_to_anchor=(1.062, 0.2),ncol=1)
    if dataL[d] != dataL[-1]:
        continue
    else: break

plt.show()
plt.close('all')
```

So the code takes data from another function and places that data into lists of lists for both the right and left data. The variables NUM_COLORS_RIGHT and NUM_COLORS_LEFT represent the number of lists that are within the lists for each side, respectively. Those variables are then used to determine the number of colors that should be used to plot the data, so as to make use of the color map and prevent the re-use of colors when plotting an indefinite number of text files.

Both plots are on the bottom so I need to move the plot from dataR[I] onto the figure above and out of the figure for dataL[d].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've mixed up two matplotlib coding styles - the object-oriented interface and the state machine. You use the variable name `ax` for both your subplots, so the reference to the first is lost, and hence you can't plot on it using `ax.plot`.

To get around that, you could call the two axes something different to each other:

```
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
cm = plt.get_cmap('gist_rainbow')
ax1.set_color_cycle([cm(1.*i/NUM_COLORS_RIGHT) for i in range(NUM_COLORS_RIGHT)])
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.set_title('Right IRI data per mile for verification runs:')
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=8)
plt.hold(True)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
cm = plt.get_cmap('gist_rainbow')
ax2.set_color_cycle([cm(1.*i/NUM_COLORS_LEFT) for i in range(NUM_COLORS_LEFT)])
ax2.grid(True)
ax2.set_title('Left IRI data per mile for verification runs:')
ax2.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=8)
plt.hold(True)

for i in range(NUM_COLORS_RIGHT):
    ax1.plot(dataR[i],linewidth=2)
    if dataR[i] != dataR[-1]:
        continue
    else: break

for d in range(NUM_COLORS_LEFT):
    ax2.plot(dataL[d],label = d,linewidth=2)
    ax2.legend(loc='lower right',borderaxespad=-4,bbox_to_anchor=(1.062, 0.2),ncol=1)
    if dataL[d] != dataL[-1]:
        continue
    else: break

plt.show()
plt.close('all')
```

If you don't want to name both subplots, you can use `plt.subplot` make the relevant subplot active again, but then you need to use `plt.plot` instead of `ax.plot`:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
cm = plt.get_cmap('gist_rainbow')
ax.set_color_cycle([cm(1.*i/NUM_COLORS_RIGHT) for i in range(NUM_COLORS_RIGHT)])
ax.grid(True)
plt.title('Right IRI data per mile for verification runs:')
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=8)
plt.hold(True)

ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
cm = plt.get_cmap('gist_rainbow')
ax.set_color_cycle([cm(1.*i/NUM_COLORS_LEFT) for i in range(NUM_COLORS_LEFT)])
ax.grid(True)
plt.title('Left IRI data per mile for verification runs:')
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=8)
plt.hold(True)

for i in range(NUM_COLORS_RIGHT):
    plt.subplot(2,1,1)
    plt.plot(dataR[i],linewidth=2)
    if dataR[i] != dataR[-1]:
        continue
    else: break

for d in range(NUM_COLORS_LEFT):
    plt.subplot(2,1,2)
    plt.plot(dataL[d],label = d,linewidth=2)
    plt.legend(loc='lower right',borderaxespad=-4,bbox_to_anchor=(1.062, 0.2),ncol=1)
    if dataL[d] != dataL[-1]:
        continue
    else: break

plt.show()
plt.close('all')
```

NOTE that the behaviour in the second example will be deprecated in a future version of matplotlib, so the first method is probably safest.

> MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.

Comment: Wow that makes a lot of sense. Ill give that a try right now